# How to get current date in C# Razor in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, date, razor

I've got some `C#` `Razor` code that is supposed to generate the current date and format it into the following string format - `yyyy-mm-dd`. It doesn't seem to be working with the code I'm using. I'm getting `2001-01-02` instead of the current date. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Doesn't the `DateTime()` give the current date by default?

```
var today = new DateTime();
var dd = today.Date.Day;

var mm = today.Month + 1;
var yyyy = today.Year;

var yyyy_string = yyyy.ToString();
var mm_string = mm.ToString();
var dd_string = dd.ToString();

if (dd < 10)
{
    dd_string = '0' + dd_string;
}

if (mm < 10)
{
    mm_string = '0' + mm_string;
}
var today_string = yyyy_string + '-' + mm_string + '-' + dd_string;
```

Comment: I don't know what `DateTime()` is but it's not standard JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I screwed up. This is actually in C# Razor, not Javascript

Comment: `new DateTime()` does **not** “generate the current date”. Any time a method doesn't do what you think it does, the first thing you should do is [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the formatted current date plus one month with

```
string today_string = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Outputs something like `"2019-07-27"` where month and day have always two digits.

Note that the format `"yyyy-M-d"` would produce months and days with one digit for numbers < 10.

The static property `DateTime.Now` yields the current date and time. We could also use `DateTime.Date` to strip off the time part, but this is not necessary, as we specify the desired format in `ToString`.

You are adding 1 to the month number. This is wrong, as in December, you would get 13. Also, at the 31st of a month (e.g. Jan 31) you would get Feb 31 as a result. So, it is better to add 1 month to the whole date with `.AddMonths(1)`. This method takes care to produce a valid date.

Comment: ".Now" does not exist for the language in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: The [System.DateTime.Now Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-1.1) exists since .Net Framework Version 1.1 and has nothing to do with the language or with Visual Studio. You must import the `System` namespace with a `using`-statement or include the namespace in the expression..

Comment: Thanks for your help. The following ended up working: DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            var dd = today.Date.Day;

            var mm = today.Month;
            var yyyy = today.Year;

Comment: Okay, but why not use the one-liner of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use DateTime.Now?;

```
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var dd = today.Date.Day;

    var mm = today.Month + 1;
    var yyyy = today.Year;

    var yyyy_string = yyyy.ToString();
    var mm_string = mm.ToString();
    var dd_string = dd.ToString();

    if (dd < 10)
    {
        dd_string = '0' + dd_string;
    }

    if (mm < 10)
    {
        mm_string = '0' + mm_string;
    }
    var today_string = yyyy_string + '-' + mm_string + '-' + 
    dd_string;
```

Comment: ".Now" does not exist for the language in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Hey mate see Olivier's answer above, generally the idea with views is that you don't put logic in there, so anything you want to use that isn't part of the @model, will need to be brought in with a using statement!  .Now is definitely there though I promise!!

Comment: The following ended up working: DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            var dd = today.Date.Day;

            var mm = today.Month;
            var yyyy = today.Year;

Comment: Glad you figured it out, Sometimes its the simple things hey haha